# When talking about bitwise operators, what does the symbol "0xf00f" mean?

Tags: bitwise-operators

Copied out the Java reference manual:

> For example, the result of the expression:
>   `0xff00 & 0xf0f0`
>   is:
>   `0xf000`
>
> The result of the expression:
>   `0xff00 ^ 0xf0f0`
>   is:
>   `0x0ff0`
>
> The result of the expression:
>   `0xff00 | 0xf0f0`
>   is:
>   `0xfff0`

What do these letters and numbers put together mean?

Comment: It all adds up to a pile of 0xDEADBEEF!

Answer (score 13):

Numbers that start in `0x` are in [hexadecimal (base 16) notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). They use digits `0-9` for hex digits `0-9`, and letters `A-F` for hex digits `10` through `15`.

Hexadecimal notation is more convenient than decimal to show bit operations, because the base 16 is `2^4`, so a digit corresponds to four bits; the results of bitwise operations are confined to a single digit; they do not "bleed" into adjacent digits.

Conversion table of binary to hex is as follows:

```
0000 - 0
0001 - 1
0010 - 2
0011 - 3
0100 - 4
0101 - 5
0110 - 6
0111 - 7
1000 - 8
1001 - 9
1010 - A
1011 - B
1100 - C
1101 - D
1110 - E
1111 - F
```

You can convert a hex number to binary by direct replacement of digits using this table. For example, `0xF0F0` becomes `1111000011110000` in binary.

With these substitution rules in hand, you can follow the text from the documentation in binary:

> 0xff00 & 0xf0f0 is: 0xf000

becomes

```
  1111 1111 0000 0000
& 1111 0000 1111 0000
---------------------
  1111 0000 0000 0000
```

In binary it makes more sense: the result of a bitwise `&` is `1` only when both operands have `1` in the corresponding bit; otherwise, the result is `0`.

You should be able to follow the remaining operations `^` and `|` more readily as well.

Comment: Summary: The reason for hexadecimal -- or another base with a power of 2, but hexadecimal is just a good fit as two map to 8-bits -- when talking about bit-wise operations is that it is *much* easier to see what is occurring than if it were shown using decimal numbers ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot! i thought it was hex to decimal. but this makes a lot more sense!